# Error when using dplyr {{ }} with aggregate inside a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to use aggregate inside a function by using dplyrs {{ }} notation to select the column to aggregate on.

```
filter <- function(df, level) {
 df <- aggregate(.~ {{level}}, data=df, FUN=sum) 
 return(df)
}
```

however I get the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(phylum, '12K1B.txt', '12K2B.txt',  :  
variable lengths differ (found for '{{ level }}')
```

I have double checked my data and there are no missing or NA values and everything works as expected when I run it outside of the function so I am not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: Not my strongpoint, but I'd be surprised if rlang's `{{}}` worked inside the formula interface of `aggregate`. If you're using tidyverse, use tidyverse and go with the `dplyr::group_by` logic instead of `aggregate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{{ }}` is `tidyverse` syntax, and should only work inside `tidyverse` verbs.

If we want to achieve something like this

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris, sum)
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
2 versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3
3  virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3
```

We can make a formula on the fly, manipulating as text like so

```
aggregate_var <- function(df, level) {
  level <- deparse(substitute(level))
  aggregate(formula(paste(". ~", level)), data=df, FUN=sum) 
}

aggregate_var(iris, Species)
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
2 versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3
3  virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3
```

As an aside - `filter` is a popular function name, perhaps a more detailed description is useful. Also note that an explicit `return` statement and the assignment to `df` are not needed here.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `get` to achieve this.

```
funn <- function(df, level){
  df <- aggregate(.~ get(level), data=df, FUN=sum) 
  return(df)
}
funn(iris, "Species")

  get(level) Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3      50
2 versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3     100
3  virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3     150
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement the other answers already provided, if you wanted to use `{{`, the dplyr way is:

```
my_fun <- function(df, level) {
  df |>
    group_by({{ level }}) |>
    summarize(across(everything(), sum))
}

my_fun(iris, Species)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa             250.        171.         73.1        12.3
2 versicolor         297.        138.        213          66.3
3 virginica          329.        149.        278.        101.
```